# Allow users to add images and write code snippets in their posts in my CRUD web app like Stack Overflow, Medium

Tags: html, image, user-interface, flask, code-snippets

I have built my first *CRUD* web app thanks to *Corey Schafer's* Flask tutorial on YouTube. Been adding new features.

Currently, a user is able to create a new post that has two input entry fields - Title and Content (please see [image: New Post screenshot]). I'd like to add a feature for the users to add images and write code snippets in their posts like we can do here and on Medium. I can't seem to find any resources online on how to get started with this feature. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

### Tech Stack

- *Backend* - **Flask**.
- *Front End* - **HTML**, **CSS**, **Bootstrap** and **JS**.
- *Database* - **SQLAlchemy**.

Comment: One way you could do this is by using [flask markdown](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Markdown/). This allows you to display images, links, code blocks and more!